# Creating a driver in Matlab

Tags: matlab, device-driver

I am trying to program a rotator using Matlab, but the device is not recognized when I am using tmtool in Matlab. I have a Pascal dll library, so it is possible to program it, but I didn't use this programming language before.

My question is if you know any way to create a driver to communicate to the controller of the rotator using Matlab. I've checked the information about how to do it and it is quite confusing. I just want to move the rotator (azimuth and elevation angles) and get the value of these angles. And if the driver worked, it could be possible to programming using Matlab language or I'd need to learn Pascal?

Matlab use is required, don't ask me why.

Comment: You can load the .dll file into Matlab and use its interface to communicate with the rotator. Do you really want to reimplement the .dll functionality in Matlab?

Comment: But I don't have the .h file to load the library to Matlab using _loadlibrary_. The company that built the rotator just provide me a dll library in Pascal. That's all. I'm a newbie in this sort of things.

Comment: I'd like to avoid Pascal programming in order to use Matlab, because it is a language that I use for most of the stuff I do. So that is the problem.

Comment: You could then create your own .h file. Do you have the documentation of the .dll file? You need dll's function declarations. What function do you want to call from the dll and with what arguments?

Comment: [Library](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52yjrptg6craj3u/spidcomm-v1.17.zip) That is all the info that I have

Comment: There's a doc subfolder in your zip file that contains the description of the library. For each structure and function there is a box with C++ syntax. Copy all that info into a .h file, which you would use in loadlibrary. Let me know if you get it working. Otherwise send me the .h file you get and I will take a look.

Comment: I copied each structure and function as you said and I loaded the library, and several warnings appeared, but I don't know the next step

Comment: But I want the PC to recognize the device and then program it, so should I create a driver first and then use the library? If someone that has programmed drivers in Matlab could help me I would appreciate it.